# Cómo puedo separar un buffer en partes de 25 mb?

Tags: javascript, video, stream

Holaa, tengo un video que dura 5 minutos, y pesa 46mb, quiero separarlos en partes de 25mb cosa que ya lo tengo hecho, pero mi problema es que la primera parte del buffer, al transformarla en un video mp4, aparece como si durara 5 minutos, pero cuando llega al minuto 2:25 se corta, y la segunda parte simplemente aparece como archivo dañado.

Comment: de que manera has dividido el video?

Comment: por experiencia se que separar por megas genera ese error lo mejor es separar por tiempo y alli vas  viendo mas o menos el peso que equivale al tiempo selecionado y si lo haces asi si mostrará  los tiempos bien
ffmpeg -i video_entrada.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 1860 -f segment parte_%03d.mp4